# how convert 2014-08-07T22:35:00+04:00 into javascript time

Tags: javascript, date

I want to convert **2014-08-07T22:35:00+04:00** this string into **22:35:00** using **javascript**

please provide `jsfiddle` link

### any suggestions ?

Comment: what is this man? a question

Comment: What have you already tried? Where is your research?

Comment: ohh you wan't answer with a demo, is it the meaning of line *please provide jsfiddle link* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/PeteA/kr11waha/

```
function addZero(v) {
    if (v < 10) return '0' + v;
    return v;
}

function stripTime(ds) {
    var d = new Date(ds),
        h = addZero(d.getHours()),
        m = addZero(d.getMinutes()),
        s = addZero(d.getSeconds());

    return h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
}

document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = stripTime('2014-08-07T22:35:00+04:00');
```

That should do what you're after in pure JS